# rails namespaced controller test in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, namespaces

My specs working fine in general, but when I try to test my nested controllers I get a weird error. So this code pattern `subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_id: post.id, post_comment: attributes_for(:post_comment, post_id: post.id, user: @user) }` works fine with my controllers that are not nested, but here for my namespaced controller the test `it "saves the new task in the db` raises the following error:

```
1) Posts::PostCommentRepliesController when user is logged in POST create with valid attributes saves the new task in the db
     Failure/Error: subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_comment_id: post_comment.id, post: attributes_for(:post_comment_reply, post_comment: post_comment, user: @user) }

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (4 for 0)
```

What should I do to make this work? As you see I put my `post_comments_controller_spec.rb` in the `specs/controllers/posts` folder and require `posts/post_comments_controller`, but it doesn't help.

routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  resources :post_comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy, :show], module: :posts
end
```

spec/controllers/posts/post_comments_controller_spec.rb

```
require "rails_helper"
require "posts/post_comments_controller"

describe Posts::PostCommentsController do

  describe "when user is logged in" do

    before(:each) do
      login_user
    end

    it "should have a current_user" do
      expect(subject.current_user).to_not eq(nil)
    end

    describe "POST create" do
      let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
      let!(:post) { create(:post, user: @user) } 

      context "with valid attributes" do
        subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, post_id: post.id, post_comment: attributes_for(:post_comment, post_id: post.id, user: @user) }

        it "saves the new task in the db" do
          expect{ create_action }.to change{ PostComment.count }.by(1)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly weird bug. In short, your `let!(:post) { ... }` ended up overwriting a method called `post` on the example group that is used to issue a post request.

This happened because when you define a `let` within a `describe`, RSpec [defines you a method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers/ClassMethods#let-instance_method) of the same name within the [given example group](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/ExampleGroup).

```
describe Post do
  let(:post) { Post.new }

  it "does something" do
    post.do_something
  end
end
```

[`xhr` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e2fcb2b4aec69e10a01cebfe51bbd280ce6d5a93/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L547) (along with `get`, `post`, etc), on the other hand is a helper method for testing from Rails itself. RSpec [includes this module](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/682a12067eab233c646057f984692e3b70749f32/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb#L13) with the helper, so that it is available in the tests.

```
describe PostController, type: :controller do
  let(:comment) { Comment.new }

  it "can post a comment thanks to Rails TestCase::Behaviour" do
    post :create, comment
    # xhr :post, ... under the covers calls for post method
  end
end
```

So the example group object had a method called post, put when you created the let, RSpec went and created you a method of that same name on the group object and thus overwriting the original (and much needed) post method.

```
describe PostController, type: :controller do
  let(:post) { Post.new }

  it "mixes up posts" do
    post :create, post # post now refers to the variable, so this will cause an error
  end
end
```

To easily resolve this issue, I would recommend naming the `let(:post)` to something else, like `new_post` for example.

```
describe PostController, type: :controller do
  let(:new_post) { Post.new }

  it "does not mix up posts" do
    post :create, new_post # no more conflict
  end
end
```